# Server Connection Issue

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss5.x

**"System Error occurred.Please contact administrator"** 
 message is displayed to user.
In logs, **java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?)** exception is thrown.

This error message is displayed only to the users whose requests are redirected to 181.46 application server only.

Requests re-directed to 181.45 application server are working fine.

I think there is  **Problem connecting to network / db in one of the application servers.(Had Problem with 181.46 server )**

**i thought it might be i am  opening the connection while connecting to the database and not closing it,but it's not it.**

But anyways, The issue is getting  resolved

when i

**Stopped the server.**

Deleted log,tmp,work folders from default folder

Restarted the server.

But that is a temporary solution. Could anyone throw some light on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The system has something else running on it that is eating up all its sockets or FDs. Maybe the RAM size is less so the system might be unable to create more connection..

Comment: No , i thought initially that might be an issue , but it's not since request to one of the server is working just fine.